# Implicit Versioning (Microsoft.AspNetCore.App) with multiple class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-2.2

How should I use the implicit versioning of the *Microsoft.AspNetCore.App* package if my solution contains one web application and multiple class libraries? How can I keep the implicit versioning and still be able to use the interfaces of ASP.NET core in my class libraries?

For example, I have a new WebApplication with the following project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How can I use (for example) the ILogging interface in my `ClassLibrary1` project?

Until now I did it like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If I do it like this my project uses implicit versioning with an indirect explicit versioning...

This approach led to various different problems in the past that were always a pain to fix. I don't want to believe that this is the "go to" approach if I want to use multiple class libraries.

What is the best solution for this scenario?

Comment: You can't. Implicit versioning only works for the meta packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` / `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` and these can only be used in .NET Core (targeting `netcoreappx.y`, but not in `netstandardx.y`). See [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All metapackage for ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: So what does this mean? Everywhere on Microsofts Website it is stated that it is recommended to use "implicit versioning" yet it is almost impossible to use. I guess this has to be a common problem because who doesn't use multiple assemblies in his project?

Comment: Maybe describe describe the problems you were having. The package version (`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` in your case) is a minimum version anyways. If the main projects references a higher one, that one will be used. You could control the transient version by adding explicit `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />` to your main (executable) project, then that one will be used rather then the transient. But you can't really go lower as what `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` references

Comment: Also you should target `netstandard2.0` in your class libraries, unless you know you need a .NET Core only API (such as Span/Async extension methods for Sockets)